# Using VSPerf.exe instead of VSPerfCmd.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiling

I would like to prepare a number of Visual Studio Profiler (VSP) reports using a batch script. On Windows 7 I used VSPerfCmd.exe in the following way:

```
VSPerfCmd /start:sample /output:%OUTPUT_FILE% /launch:%APP% /args:"..."
VSPerfCmd /shutdown
```

`VSPerfCmd /shutdown` waits until the application has finished its execution, closes data collection and only then the VSP report is generated. This is what I need.

I switched to Windows Server 2012 and now `VSPerfCmd` does not work; I need to use `VSPerf` instead. The problem is that I cannot get the same behavior as VSPerfCmd.

Specifically, the `/shutdown` option is no longer available. Available options do not wait until the application has finished but stop or detach from the process right after execution. This means I can't use them in a batch script, where I run several processes one after another. Any ideas how to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually shutdown vsperf. You can simply do:

```
vsperf /launch:YourApp.exe
```

And vsperf will stop automatically after your application finishes.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977161.aspx#BKMK_Windows_8_classic_applications_and_Windows_Server_2012_applications_only

Comment: In visual studio 2013 `vsperf /launch:YourApp.exe` does not wait for YourApp.exe to end